# Can you configure font for Query Editor in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to configure the font used for the Query editor in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010?

I found this same question for VS 2005 and the answer from Microsoft saying you can't.  I'm hoping that this is not true with 2008 or 2010.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/a4aa8790-7a72-4e0f-8901-0188ec0f3104

This is the screen shot from 2005 but it's almost the same in 2008.

[image: VS 2005]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure this font.

Answer (score 0):

I have never touched the Query Editor, so this is going to be untested, but as of VS 2008, a new option under Fonts/Colors was added to control the font for IDE elements that had no 'Show settings for' option.

The new option is called 'Environment Font' under the 'Show settings for:' combo box in 'Fonts and Colors'.

Comment: That changed the settings for pretty much everything else, but not the query editor.